# ObjectToJson thorwn System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, memorystream, datacontractjsonserializer

I use this construction.

```
public static string ObjectToJson<TObject>(TObject obj)
{
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer((obj.GetType()));
            ser.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                var st = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return st;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

How to improve it code so that this error does not occur?
I think this is happend because I use memostream

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could simply use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or any other developed libraries for that

Comment: What is in the object? Any large strings or byte arrays etc? What is the value of `obj.GetType()`

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Object contains large List<string>

Comment: How large is large? What problem are you trying to solve by serializing a large string list to JSON, and then returning that JSON as a string?

Comment: I try to improve this method. I think we do not need know what object small or big

Comment: `I think we do not need know what object small or big` If you have the solution, then feel free to push back on our questions. Until that point, it is generally frowned upon to try and resist our attempts to help you.

Comment: I do not have solution. I try find solution. I want to concentration from optimization this method

Comment: @user3820635 What's error that you're getting?